# How to limit the number of nodes at the account level in slurm?

Tags: bash, scheduling, slurm, hpc

I would like to know how to limit the number of nodes a single job can use by the account level on slurm.

```
sacctmgr modify account where name=test9_phase1 set MaxTRESPerJob=nodes=1
```

This doesnt seem to work, giving the error:

```
 Unknown option: MaxTRESPerJob=nodes=1
 Use keyword 'where' to modify condition
```

and I can't find anything in the documentation on how to do it.

If I could limit it by user that would also work, but again I get an error

```
sacctmgr modify user where cluster=linux account=test9_phase1 set maxTRESPerJob=nodes=1
 Unknown option: maxTRESPerJob=nodes=1
 Use keyword 'where' to modify condition
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct option to set is [MaxNodesPerJob](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html#OPT_MaxNodesPerJob=). The `sacctmgr` output can be a bit misleading there.

So in your case, the correct command should be:

```bash
sacctmgr modify account where name=test9_phase1 set MaxNodesPerJob=1
```